# Imagemagick with find in bash script : output in current folder

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I have subfolders with png images inside. I want to convert them to jpeg with a static name (there is only one image per folder). The images need to be outputted in the same folder as the original image.

This bash script

```
#! /bin/sh    

find . -type f -name '*.png' -exec convert "{}" *OPTIONS* mydefinedname.jpg \;
```

doesn't work because the output is always the root folder, so it erases each previous jpeg with the current one.

Ho to tell convert ? The help file isn't clear on this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `-exec`, use `-execdir`, which runs the command in the directory the file is in, rather than the current working directory:

```
find . -type f -name '*.png' -execdir convert "{}" *OPTIONS* mydefinedname.jpg \;
```